# Can a variable be used inside a function without a Global declaration inside that function

Tags: python

CODE 1:

```
x=4    
def func():
          print("HELLO WORLD")
          y=x+2
          print (y)
          print (x) # gives o/p as HELLO WORLD 6,4,4.

func()    
print (x)
```

CODE 2:

```
x=4    
def func():

          print("HELLO WORLD")
          y=x+2
          x=x+2 # gives an error here
          print (y)
          print (x) 

func()
print (x)
```

In the first code, it is not showing any error, it's adding the `x` value to 2 and resulting back to `y` and it prints the o/p as `6,4,4`. But Actually as I learnt so for, it should point an error because I am not giving the global declaration for `x` variable inside the `func()`. But its not ponting any error but in `Code 2` it gives an error saying that `x referenced before assignment`.

The question is can `x` can be used for the assignment of its value to other variables? Even it is not followed with global declaration?

Comment: This is python, could you please stop using semicolons?

Comment: ofcourse cularis but it gives users more readability if you use semi colons so i used it

Comment: In what way is a semicolon increasing readability? It is useless in your code above.

Comment: ofcourse but for me and some people it increases the readability

Comment: ok sorry from now i stop using semicolon

Comment: i'm programmer in c for months i used up with that syntax i started learning python from 2 days back everything seems clear to me but the indentation part its confusing writing a function inside a function all those stuff

Comment: you stop using semicolons not only for now but forever - or may get further -1 votes :-)

Comment: I did it Black moon from my next python qeustions Thank you

Comment: Is it okay now Blackmoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read global variables without explicitly declaring them as global (Code 1)

But you are not allowed to assign to a global variable without explicitely declaring it as global. (Code 2)

This is because there is no harm in reading, but when assigning you might get unexpected behaviour (especially if it's a long code with many variables and you think it's a unique name you are using, but it's not).

Answer (score 1):

In the first function you haven't assigned to x, so the compiler doesn't treat it as a local variable. The runtime will automatically get x from the containing scope. You can easily inspect that x is not considered a local variable:

```
>>> func1.__code__.co_varnames
('y',)
```

In the 2nd function you're assigning to x, so the compiler treats it as a local variable:

```
>>> func2.__code__.co_varnames
('x', 'y')
```

Hence the error you see: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`.